# Eclipse debugger and collections

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have some collections that I would like to analyze in the Eclipse debugger. I am interested in a particular attribute of each element.

Let's take an example with a list of `Person`s (each one with an `address` attribute which in turn has a `city` attribute). In the debugger I can either look at each element or look at `list.get(i).address.city`.

Doing this for large structures is not really helpful. Is there the possibility to apply a function to a data structure, something similar to the `map` function in Perl (in the debugger not in the code).

The input would be my list with the path I am interested in (Person.address.city), the output a list with just the selected elements (a list of cities with my example).

In Perl:

```
map { $_->{address}->{city} } @list
```

**Edit**

I am able to generate a `String` with a *Detail Formatter*:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Person p : this) {
    sb.append(p.address.city());
    sb.append(", ");
}
return sb.toString();
```

This will format my list with just the elements I am interested in (as a `String`).

Although it goes in the right direction it would be nice if I could return a new `List` that I can analyze with the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the Eclipse Debugger feature you are interested is called logical structures. You could define a logical structure in Eclipse preferences (Java/Debug/Logical structures), where you could write such an expression (hopefully), and then on the variables view you could replace the display of the list in the pop-up menu.

See this blog post for basic ideas: http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16736&messageID=91823528

Answer (score 2):

The **Display** View provides you with the ability to execute custom code at each breakpoint. Just read out your data structure at the breakpoint and print it out to the console.